Different projection matrices, don't understand how to proceed
I'm stuck on the second part of an exercise:
In $\mathcal{E}^2$, identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$ through an orthonormal reference system $(i, j)$, be Pr: $\mathcal{E}^2 \to \mathcal{E}^2$, $v \mapsto v'$ the orthogonal projection along the direction of the vector $i - j$.
Determine the projection matrix directly by calculating the matrix and by calculating the images of the vectors of the reference system.
Here is what I have done
What I know from the theory is that I can immediately solve the first way by knowing that the "direction vector" is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$, call it $b$.
Then
$$\text{Pr} = \dfrac{b b^t}{b^t b} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
And this is fine, I also made a drawing to check visually.
Yet I cannot find the same result in the other way, by the images.
Indeed I have $i' = i$ and $j' = -j$, according to the direction of the vector $i-j$, hence the images are $i' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $j' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$, which as columns are definitely not the same matrix as before.
I cannot understand this part, how should I proceed?

The orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $v$ is $$Px=\frac{v^txv}{v^tv}.$$
So the first column of $P$ is, since $v^tv=2$ for $v=i-j$,
$$
P\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\frac12\,\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}
$$
And the second column is
$$
P\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\frac12\,\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here is a visual representation:

$AB$ is the $i-j$ line. The projection of $D$ is $E$ so $(1,0)\to(1/2,-1/2)$. Similarly for the other direction, $(0,1)\to(-1/2,1/2)$.
